# SL 4 -- Force redraw of visual tree

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Our application has a number of objects on a canvas; the canvas is contained in a scroll viewer.  We also have a slider control and some buttons, always centered at the top of the window.
I am trying to print the application by capturing a bitmap of the app, but without any 'decorations' -- slider, buttons, or scroll bars.

```
        _scrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden;
        _scrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden;
        var s = xSlider;
        s.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        var b = xPlusButton;
        b.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        b = xMinusButton;
        b.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        b = xButton;
        b.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

The slider and buttons are hidden, as expected, but the scrollbars are not.
I suspect the application needs to redraw the layout in order to hide the scrollbars.  Is there a way to make that happen?  This is made more complicated by the fact that the print operation in SL 4 must be initiated by a UI gesture; there is no way (AFAIK) to initiate programatically, so this redraw must happen in one of the PrintDocument event handlers.

Thanks for any suggestions....

Comment: Can you show the Xaml of the Canvas that you are printing?  The "capturing a bitmap" comment sounds a bit off, can you eloborate?

Comment: I can't really show the xaml, since all the objects are added at runtime, and make heavy use of templates.  I believe it is the templates causing the mischief; after passing the Canvas to the PrintDocument, the tree is never redrawn (at least not completely).  What shows up as the print output is a lot of missing or incompletely drawn objects.
We are trying to capture a bitmap of the Canvas to get around the incompletely drawn object problem.

Comment: Can you post your code of capturing bitmap?

Answer (score 7):

Try following,

```
canvas.InvalidateMeasure();
canvas.InvalidateArrange();
```

You can alternatively use WritableBitmap to capture runtime image and send image to print document if in case print document is ignoring render transform.

Also if you are using WritableBitmap to capture the element then you should give RenderTransform as second argument. Can you post your code to capture screen?

Comment: +1 for getting it right!  This was exactly what I needed to force the LayouUpdated event to fire.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the InvalidateMeasure and InvalidateArrange methods, as suggested by Akash, you can try the [UpdateLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.updatelayout%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) method.

The two invalidate methods will mark the control's measure or arrange as needing to be executed again, but won't necessarily do it immediately. The UpdateLayout will force it to execute some updates immediately.

It's a bit of a black box, so you may need to invalidate then call UpdateLayout. Sometimes you may just need to call UpdateLayout.